# Acumatica - Override ConvertQuoteToProject to include custom fields

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to override the base method ConvertQuoteToProject in PMQuoteMaint so that I can add our custom fields from the Project that are required. Currently with the required fields in Project, we cannot convert the Quote.

Partial Snippet:

```
    public virtual void ConvertQuoteToProject(PMQuote row, ConvertToProjectFilter settings)
        {
            if (!ValidateQuoteBeforeConvertToProject(row))
            {
                throw new PXException(Messages.QuoteConversionFailed);
            }
    
            ProjectEntry projectEntry = CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();
            projectEntry.Clear();
    
            PMProject project = new PMProject();
            project.BaseType = PMProject.ProjectBaseType.Project;
            
            CM.CurrencyInfo info = PXSelect<CM.CurrencyInfo, Where<CurrencyInfo.curyInfoID, Equal<Current<PMQuote.curyInfoID>>>>.Select(this);
            info.CuryInfoID = null;
            info = (CM.CurrencyInfo)projectEntry.Caches<CM.CurrencyInfo>().Insert(info);
            project.CuryID = row.CuryID;
            project.CuryInfoID = info.CuryInfoID;
            project.RateTypeID = info.CuryRateTypeID;
            
            if (!DimensionMaint.IsAutonumbered(this, ProjectAttribute.DimensionName))
                project.ContractCD = row.QuoteProjectCD;
                    
            project = projectEntry.Project.Insert(project);
    
            project.CustomerID = row.BAccountID;
            if (row.LocationID != null)
                project.LocationID = row.LocationID;
            if (row.TermsID != null)
                project.TermsID = row.TermsID;
            project.QuoteNbr = row.QuoteNbr;

            project.UsrOffice = row.UsrOffice;
            project.UsrBuildingtype = row.UsrBuildingtype;
            project.UsrProjAdmin = row.UsrProjAdmin;
            project.UsrProjectManager = row.UsrProjectManager;

            project = projectEntry.Project.Update(project);
```

In a customization, even trying a simple override of the method throws this error:

```
Method Void ConvertQuoteToProject(PX.Objects.PM.PMQuote, ConvertToProjectFilter, ConvertQuoteToProjectDelegate) in graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but its signature is not compatible with original method
```

Customization Code:

```
    public delegate void ConvertQuoteToProjectDelegate(PMQuote row, ConvertToProjectFilter settings);
[PXOverride]
public void ConvertQuoteToProject(PMQuote row, ConvertToProjectFilter settings, ConvertQuoteToProjectDelegate baseMethod)
{
  baseMethod(row,settings);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this would be to trap the event that ties the two together and update additional fields.

In that function there is this block:

```
        project.CustomerID = row.BAccountID;
        if (row.LocationID != null)
            project.LocationID = row.LocationID;
        if (row.TermsID != null)
            project.TermsID = row.TermsID;
        project.QuoteNbr = row.QuoteNbr;
        project = projectEntry.Project.Update(project);
```

You could do a graph extension of the project entry and tie to updating quoteNbr, the foreign key.

```
    public virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<PMProject.quoteNbr> e, PXFieldUpdated del)
    {
        del?.Invoke(e.Cache, e.Args);
        string QuoteNbr = (string)e.NewValue;
        //Get the quote
        var Quote = PMQuote.PK.Find(Base, QuoteNbr);
        if (Quote != null)
        {
            //get your dac extension
            PMQuoteExt quoteExt = Quote.GetExtension<PMQuoteExt>();
            //now set values based on your extension            
            e.Cache.SetValueExt<PMProjectExt.field>(e.Row, ext.field);
        }
    }
```